# Moderator Position Open -- Nominees Needed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators

#### Update:

We have accepted Yvette's nomination as a pro tem Moderator.  Congratulations! Access should be enabled shortly.

---

We last had a pro tem nomination thread in late 2015, so it's time again to fill in [a 3rd Moderator](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) for this site.

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Comment: If anyone has [questions or concerns before nominating for this position,](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37804042#37804042) I would be happy to address them in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box)

Comment: Robert, when I put the code into Yvette's nomination I had to change 'http' to 'https' presumably your copy and paste is outdated.  Also the Meta flair for her is not showing correctly to me.  I see the Main site flair but the meta flair is showing as a tiny image icon space holder.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Ah yes. With the https: switchover, "meta.pets" has become "pets.meta". Thanks, I will make the correct adjustments.

Comment: Robert, we are down to 2 mods again, and have been discussing in chat about asking for a third.  Would you like us to have interested parties post here? As it is fairly current, here seems like a good option but the choice is yours.

Comment: @JamesJenkins With the low turnout in this last cycle, we decided to let a bit of time pass before starting another nomination thread. I was going to start another post soon after 1-Aug, but if the situation is dire, send an email to the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the site.

Comment: Not dire, After August 1 is fine.  We will keep gathering support in chat.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I'll nominate myself. I was with Pets.se in Area 51 and when it was first launched. Took a break from the network and have returned as a solid contributor to the network for some time.

As a level headed and consistent contributor to the Stack Exchange networks, Pets being one of my pet sites *(dreadful pun intended)*, I would to seek advice from other mods or the Team is there's particularly sticky situations.

I believe in encouraging newcomers to the site and assisting in educating users how to use the site.

The pets.se review tab is one of my browser start up tabs. So I check multiple times per day if there's any review items. In the same way I can check for flags. I work from home on a PC and do not have restrictions accessing the site.

While still asking and answering questions,  my contributions are more based with moderation activity currently.

Past experience:

I studied first year veterinary science, which included animal husbandry.

I've worked in animal rescue on and off over the years.

I've used to teach puppy training.

Currently we own:

3 horses (2 rescue)
1 rescue greyhound
3 rescue cats

From [the comments](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2168/moderator-position-open-nominees-needed?cb=1#comment4866_2169):

> With 10k+ rep you already have access to most of the mod level tools.
>   Question for you, should be given the moderator diamond what do you
>   think your most difficult challenge(s) will be and how will you
>   overcome it/them?

I have given this question much thought as I can do many things that the mods can also do.

There's a few considerations that I would need to be mindful of.

**Binding Votes**

Binding votes. Rather than jump in with a binding vote, if a case is at all borderline of whether a question is on topic, I'd wait for the community to decide.

**If in doubt - seek advice**

Handling conflict and distressed users and potential suspensions is a big responsibility. Being, potentially, my first position as a mod, I'd seek the guidance of [James](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13/james-jenkins) and [Ash](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/users/53/ash), who are both experienced as mods, if I was at all unsure of how to use the moderator tools. I wouldn't rush into things.

**Flags**

I'd look forward to using the mod powers to handle flags, and to remove rude/abusive and spam content from the site quickly. I'm a member of [Charcoal HQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), which is [dedicated to removing spam and abusive posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically) that make it through the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) spam filters.

**Privacy**

As a moderator I'd have access to some private details about users and I take confidentiality as an important responsibility. For some time I worked in a hospital and was in a department that handled sensitive information, for which staff could be legally prosecuted for leaking information. This was a position I felt pleased to procure, as it was an indictment of my trustworthy ability to preserve privacy laws.

**Community reputation**

As a moderator I feel that there's a responsibility to behave professionally. To set an example and to take a pride in the community's reputation. This is something that I feel high rep user's should have, and as such I already take this seriously and attempt to always uphold this.

The only hesitation I have, is winning community support on this point, as there were [some problems with me on the site when it was first launched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293213/why-dont-we-keep-public-records-of-suspensions/293335#293335). This would, understandably make some longer time members of our community uneasy and I understand if this makes people hesitant to give me such a position.

At the time I was unwell and since have been and continue to be treated effectively. If I feel myself slipping I stay offline and get the appropriate help. The good news is, I have been stable for some time now and am able to manage my illness effectively.

Comment: I'd vote for her if community members had a way to, not that a newbie has much say... I haven't been on this site long but she has a ton of activity and it appears to be daily, positive, informative and supportive from what I've read. Oops meant to be a comment not answer, didn't realize I couldn't delete it

Comment: @ChristyB. everyone has equal say, To vote just up vote her nomination.

Comment: Your recent [answer here](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2132) indicates you have a good handle on the difficulty of some of the posts & people.  Over the last few months you have also shown good judgement in a number of situations, as well as being active across the site.  With 10k+ rep you already have access to most of the mod level tools. Question for you, should be given the moderator diamond what do you think your most difficult challenge(s) will be and how will you overcome it/them?