# Will you help moderate this site? Nominations needed

Tags: discussion, moderators

#### Update:

We have accepted Rebecca RVT and Henders' nomination as a pro tem Moderators. Congratulations! Their access should be enabled shortly.

[image]

[image]

---

We recently posted [a nomination thread](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2168/moderator-position-open-nominees-needed) to appoint another moderator; unfortunately, we only had one user willing to step up and we need more users to fill in another vacancy.

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election [**→ we *need* three provisional Moderators ←**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) to fill those roles. It is critical to the continuation of this site.

Please nominate yourself below if interested; otherwise, please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: [Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

Good luck!

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Answer (score 15):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I would like to self-nominate.

**Why Me**

- I love animals and love to help people.
- Got my certificate for Veterinary Technician in spring 2013 - Licensed in summer of 2013
- Worked in many veterinary hospitals around Canada, 1 year in New-Brunswick, 1 year in Newfoundland, 2 years in Nova Scotia and now I am working in Ontario. Having different experiences in each province has broadened my knowledge on internal medicine and surgery.
- I contribute quite a bit in regards to answers, I am [top 0.42% this year](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/265/year/pets/2017-01-01/7526#7526) and was [ranked #1 last year](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/265/year/pets/2016-01-01) even though I joined a bit late.
- I have a vast amount of experience in the field to help clarify answers and questions.
- I am fluent in French and English - an asset to those who need help translating.
- I have a TON of patience for people who ask what most would call a common sense question - no question is a dumb question in my books.

**What I Am Working On**

- Flagging, editing and casting votes.

I honestly didn't notice the flags and edits before Zaralynda pointed it out as well as the importance of casting votes. Now it's something I engage in daily and will continue to work at as time goes on.

I never moderated on a website so this will be new for me however when I have a job I take it seriously.

As this is my first time applying for something like this I'm not 100% sure this is the information you guys are looking for so feel free to comment on what else I can add or should remove.

Comment: omg this is a [beautiful nomination!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39170249#39170249)  We're so happy to have you on the site, your contributions have been amazing.

Comment: Great candidate here - Active in chat too and very welcoming when I joined up :)

Answer (score 9):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

#### Why Not Me?

**Elephant in the room** - My reputation on this site is definitely not the highest because until recently I wasn't a heavy contributor. As an active member in [Charcoal-HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) I spoke with Yvette just after she became a moderator and she reminded me to participate here.

Since then, I've [answered](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/6826/henders?tab=answers) and [asked](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/6826/henders?tab=questions) all the questions that I can (to what I believe is a high standard). As per [the conversation we had in The Litter Box](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/conversation/discussing-moderation-on-pets-se), I have tried to gain as much rep as I can because it is probably regarded as my weak point here.

#### Why Me?

I may be new (reputation-wise) to this site, but I am not new to 'moderating as a user' on the stack exchange websites. Right from my beginning on **StackOverflow (SO) 4 years, 4 months ago**, I have been flagging content, editing posts and working with current Network moderators to keep the network clean.

#### Network Stats:

- I have over **2,600 helpful flags** (99.81% total) over the whole StackExchange network (639 of which are [Smoke Detector Auto-Flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically))
- **176 edited posts** (28 here and counting)
- **~440 Reviews** (First posts, triage, late answers etc... 55 here already)
- Lurker in [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) so I understand how Close Voting and user led moderation works.

I am a **member of [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/)** where we use [Smoke Detector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) and a [dedicated chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) to **fight spam across the network**. I have [over 3,000 valid feedbacks](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/admin/user_feedback?user_id=256) to help validate the system's filter criteria. I'm also ['frequently in [the] room'](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/10964/the-litter-box) at [The Litter Box](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box) and try to be the first respondent to review tasks when I'm awake.

I have a few years of experience moderating other (less hospitable) communities than SE so I've gained the thick skin required. I have always found that you get the best out of people when you're friendly, firm, helpful and have the ability to *listen* to users especially in situations that have the propensity to escalate.

I hope you can see by looking through my contributions to the site so far that my lack of reputation at this stage is balanced by experience with moderation tasks because I firmly believe I can help to moderate this community and help shape its future.

#### Personal Highlights

[Why did my Guppies not grow for 8 months?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17630/why-did-my-guppies-not-grow-for-8-months/17631#17631)

[Will cooking rocks and branches in the oven make them safe for aquarium fish?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17885/will-cooking-rocks-and-branches-in-the-oven-make-them-safe-for-aquarium-fish/17887#17887)

[Gourami breathing at water's surface](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17757/gourami-breathing-at-waters-surface/17758)

<sub>I'd love feedback, both positive and negative :)</sub>

Comment: *less hospitable* ... citation needed?

Comment: @rene - It was part of an online community game where people had paid for content and the code admins had made some game mechanic changes which the majority of people were not happy about. The team which helped moderate the game bore the brunt of the backlash. My statement was what I've seen come through Smokey and what mods have said about messages they have received in the line of duty.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just curious. Good luck!

Comment: @rene it's so good to see you flower man!! :D

Comment: I think you'd make a great mod - the only thing holding you back at this stage is the short time active here - but that will obviously change with time. Great nomination - very thorough. :)

Comment: Thanks, @YvetteColomb - I agree, it would take a lot of trust for the community to accept me at this stage but I'm certainly willing and ready to learn :)

Comment: @Henders if you're not elected this time, I am sure you will be down the track. Also it's not up to the community -it's up to the team - which you probably know

Comment: Thanks :) There's always things to work on, either way!